# IcCube - How to center Multi-Headers pivots tables Top-Header row labels?

Tags: css, themes, iccube, iccube-reporting

With no modification in V7 IcCube reporting, a Pivot table with multiple header rows had labels centered automatically. In V8, I cannot find how to reproduce this.

Here is what we have in V7 : 1st row header labels are centered accross their 3 columns total length.
[image]

And what we get in V8 :
[image]

How can we center this again by default in V8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current limitation: only the last row of the top header is respecting the `Header Alignment` configuration. This will be changed in the upcoming version (v8.3): this configuration will apply to all the rows.